# Why RFNA is used in orbital rocket and why it leaks?

Tags: launch, rockets, fuel

The red fume can be seen in some ballistic missile tests and of course here for the case of Chinese KZ-1A orbital launcher. i wonder what's the usage and why it leaks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Red fuming nitric acid is used as a storable non cryogenic oxidizer. It does not leak, its fumes are vented, I guess to prevent a tank overpressure.

[image]

From this [pdf](http://publications.drdo.gov.in/gsdl/collect/defences/index/assoc/HASH014d.dir/doc.pdf) *Problems in Storage and Handling of Red Fuming Nitric Acid*

So there might be too few NO2 and H2O within the mixture. Adding water would be dead weight, but 2 to 3.5 % should not be a problem.

Comment: I suppose it is used in this rocket because of it missile origin. However does IRFNA has any advantages compared to N2O4? (As I understand, military values lower freezing point but for the launch system that's probably not as crucial)